# How can I conditionally add or remove CSS classes in Aurelia repeat.for?

Tags: aurelia

I have an array of stuff from which I am building a `<select>` and I want to be able to mark the `first` item as disabled using CSS, however I cannot get the syntax right.

Here's what I have:

```
<select select2 value.bind="selectedItem">
    <option repeat.for="item of stuff" model.bind="item" class="${${first} ? 'disabled selected hidden' : ''">
        ${item.key}
    </option>
</select>
```

[HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/mEpr8E?p=preview)'s a `Plunker` similar enough that can be used as a test-bed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your example is not full, but I guess it should look like:

```
class="${item.first ? 'disabled selected hidden' : ''}"
```

Also if you have `first` property at VM, like `stuff` you write:

```
class="${$parent.first == item? 'disabled selected hidden' : ''}"
```

UPDATE:

Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/2xywp0)

```
<option repeat.for="thing of things" model.bind="thing">${thing.name} ${$first | stringify}</option>
```

You just have wrong syntax here: `class="${${first} ? 'disabled selected hidden' : ''"` should be `class="${ $first ? 'disabled selected hidden' : '' }"`

From Aurelia docs:

```
Contextual items availabe inside a repeat template:

$index - The index of the item in the array.
$first - True if the item is the first item in the array.
$last - True if the item is the last item in the array.
$even - True if the item has an even numbered index.
$odd - True if the item has an odd numbered index.
```

Comment: didn't work I am afraid :-( I have added a `Plunker` to make it easier to test. Please note that I would like to leverage the `$first` as included in the Aurelia doc instead of having to create another property on the VM.

Comment: It turned out I had 2 extra braces! so it should have been `${$first ?...` instead of `${${first} ?...`

Comment: yes, right syntax is `class="${ $first ? 'disabled selected hidden' : '' }"`